# Change textview depending on time

Tags: android, textview, clock

I want to change my TextView content depending on the date & time, Currently I have one text view which outputs the date and time, I want another text view to look at it and if its greater than 17:00 and the date is 24/04/2016 then it changes the text to closed. Alternatively could I use a textclock which my textview looks at?

// Display current date and time

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    tv.setText(currentDateandTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
txt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             // write the condition for second textview here
             if(date.equals("24/04/2016") && time.equals("17:00"))
             {
                    txt2.setText("closed");
             }

            }
        });
```